# How to find intersection between a specific node and its neighbors in Spark GraphX with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph

i am new to spark graphx and trying to compute distributedly the  intersection between a specific node for example node with ID = 1 with its neighbors in spark GraphX.

i have loaded edge list with GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,"Path"). and then i find neighbors ID for node id =1 with collectNeighborIds and i do a map function on it to find the each neighbor neighbors and compute intersection with selected node(node with ID =1) neighbors.
Here is the code.

```
val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,path to edgelist)
val node_collect_neighborsId1 = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).filter(x=> x._1 == 1)

val node1_neighbors_ID=node_collect_neighborsId1.flatMap(x=> x._2)

def compute_intersection (vertex :VertexId) = {


  var node2_collect_neighborsId: RDD[(VertexId, Array[VertexId])] = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).filter(x=> x._1 == vertex)

  var node2_neighbors_ID=node2_collect_neighborsId.flatMap(x=> x._2)

  var intersect_two_node = node1_neighbors_ID.intersection(node2_neighbors_ID)

  (vertex, intersect)

}

val result = node1_neighbors_ID.map(compute_intersection)
```

i expect at the end, the result variable should contain rows that include vertex id that is the id of neighbor and common nodes between two set of node neighbors that we have called intersection on them. but i cant print them and see what is inside it. 
please help me with this problem on computing intersection and printing the result

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input and output?

Comment: for example node 1 has this neighbors => (2,3,4,5) and each of this nodes have their own neighbors, for example node 2 has this neighbors =>(3,5,8). the numbers are nodes ID. in this case the intersection of node 1 and 2 will be (3,5). i want to get this result for all of neighbors with map function and calling the compute_intersection function to compute them and store in result variable that it is an RDD. but i cant print the result to see what is in it and i am not sure that the code i have wrote is correct

Comment: i am working on community detection and in one part of it i need to get the similarity between one node and its neighbors, and for doing this, i need to get the intersection between chosen node and its neighbors. this is the problem i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build a result of type `RDD[RDD[T]]`. Hence you shouldn't compute intersection for each neighbor inside `map`.

You can compute intersection for all target's neighbors with `aggregateMessages`:

```
def computeIntersection[VD, ED](graph: Graph[VD, ED], targetVertexId: Long): VertexRDD[List[Long]] = {
  //mark the target's neighbors
  val verticesWithTargetNeighborFlag = graph.aggregateMessages[Boolean](
    triplet => {
      if(triplet.srcId == targetVertexId && triplet.dstId != targetVertexId) {
        triplet.sendToDst(true)
      } else if(triplet.dstId == targetVertexId && triplet.dstId != targetVertexId) {
        triplet.sendToSrc(true)
      }
    },
    (msg1, msg2) => msg1 || msg2,
    TripletFields.None
  )
  val graphWithTargetNeighborFlag = Graph(verticesWithTargetNeighborFlag, edges)
  //collect intersection vertices for each target's neighbor
  val verticesWithIntersection = graphWithTargetNeighborFlag.aggregateMessages[List[Long]](
    triplet => if (triplet.srcAttr && triplet.dstAttr) { //both are target's neighbors
      triplet.sendToDst(List(triplet.srcId))
      triplet.sendToSrc(List(triplet.dstId))
    },
    (msg1, msg2) => msg1 ::: msg2,
    TripletFields.All
  )
  verticesWithIntersection
}
```

And you can print RDD elements using `collect`:

```
rdd.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your greate help. it solved my problem,

Comment: i have my last question: i made some changes to my code and use broadcast variables and it worked. but i dont know does this code run in parallel and distributed or not?? the code look like this:   val brdcast = sc.broadcast(node_collect_neighborsId1.collect()) and the compute_intersection function includes just this code:   var intersect_nodes = (brdcast.value.flatMap(x=> x._2).toSeq).intersect((graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).filter(x=> x._1 == vertex).collect().flatMap(x=> x._2).toSeq));  (intersect_nodes).  does this code run in distributed manner?

Comment: i mean by using collect and toSeq, does the code again run in distributed manner or it just collect everything to master node and does not run in distributed?

Comment: No, it's not. broadcast.value is plan scala collection, not an rdd. Also, collect execution result exists on the driver (it isn't distributed across executers). So brdcastValue.flatMap(collectResult) is just a scala collection transformation, not parallel execution.

Comment: thank you for your perfect answer. you really helped me with this problem.thanks

Comment: Mr. Aleksey Isachnekov is it possible for you just have a look at this problem in below link. its one of my main problem. if you can help i would be so thankful from you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547724/what-is-best-structure-to-choose-for-updaing-nodes-property-in-spark-graphx

Comment: I wrote some comments on this question.

Comment: today i saw and good question looks like my question. its about Pregel. can you please have a look at this question? this is the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128932/how-to-implement-a-written-code-in-aggregatemessages-in-pregel-api-in-spark